# Facebook GraphRequest Android sdk v4

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook android sdk api documentation declared graphRequest as follows

```java
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
        // App Code
    }
});
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link");
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();`
```

My problem is in the onCompleted there we get a JSONObject and a GraphResponse type response, what is the use of those two to return types?? How can I use them efficiently??

Comment: you can parse the JSON. The response to you request should be in there.

Answer (score 0):

The Difference between those JSONObject and GraphResponse

**JSONObject**:

1. It Contains the rawResponse(Data) of the GraphRequest. Inside the rawResponse you did't get information about the API error's and response code for the API call

**GraphResponse**:

1. This class object contains the full information about the API Response. So you can check whether your GraphRequest is succeeded or failed.
2. JSONObject is one of the GraphResponse class member. So if you want you can get JSONObject from GraphResponse.

**Best Approach**:

Use the GraphResponse from this check whether your request failed or succeeded. Using below line of code.

```
response.error
```

it will return null if Your Request is success or returns string on failure.

If you want JSONObject from GraphResponse you will from

```
response.getJSONObject()   -----> it returns the JSONObject (graphObject).
```